# Como bloquear um arquivo executável e impedí-lo de abrir no Windows?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, arquivo

Gostaria de criar um programa particular onde eu possa bloquear programas de executar no Windows, sei que o próprio Windows fornece algo básico sobre isso, mas eu queria criar o meu programa, alguém me de uma dica de código que bloqueia qualquer arquivo executável no Windows.

Comment: Dê uma olhada no [tour]. Você pode aceitar uma resposta se ela resolveu seu problema. Você pode votar em todos os posts do site também. Alguma lhe ajudou mais? Precisa que algo seja melhorado?

Answer (score 6):

Precisa colocar no registro do Windows usando a classe [`RegistryKey`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.win32.registrykey?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0):

```
using (RegistryKey chave = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer", true)) {
    chave.SetValue("DisallowRun", 1);
}
using (RegistryKey chave = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey(@"Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun", true)) {
    chave.SetValue("1", "executável que quer aqui");
}
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Enviroment/Registry.cs).

[Achei a chave nessa página](http://www.howtogeek.com/180803/how-to-block-an-application-or-.exe-from-running-in-windows/).

[Documentação](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/ms811970(v=msdn.10)?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Não sei se tem alguma implicação mas é possível trocar o `CurrentUser` por `LocalMachine`. Não garanto que vai funcionar corretamente ou terá que mexer em alguma coisa, mas é uma tentativa para fazer globalmente.

Também seria possível fazer uma representação ([`WindowsIdentity`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.security.principal.windowsidentity?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397&view=net-5.0)), ou pode ainda carregar o perfil de um usuário (`LoadUserProfile`) mas não tem métodos prontos para usar com C#, teria que fazer um *binding* para a API.

Obviamente tudo exige que tenha privilégios de administrador. Não existe milagre.

Comment: olá, bigown, perdoa a ignorância mas nunca vi a using de "RegistryKey" e não consigo colocar as diretrizes necessárias, para tirar o erro.

Comment: Aí você precisa fazer outra pergunta mais específica mostrando o que está fazendo e perguntando pelo problema.

Comment: que pena! é que você cita, classe RegistryKey: e chave = a Registry do que se trata, pois gostaria de explicar na pergunta.

Comment: @NilceliaPereira A calsse RegistryKey acessa o registro do Windows, o que a resposta do bigown propõe é bloquear pelo explorer.exe os aplicativos usado os registros, algo semelhante ao `regedit`. O `Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey` acessa um registro especifico usado pelo explorer.exe e o `chave.SetValue` define o comportamento, realmente é uma ótima solução para o seu problema, eu só não tenho certeza se o comportamento do `Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\DisallowRun` funciona para versões como WinXp e Vista. Mas tente usar ela, parece ser bem o que procura :) - +1

Comment: @NilceliaPereira a vantagem de perguntar separado cada problema é que fica muito mais fácil para outras pessoas com a mesma dúvida localizarem o conteúdo, e dividindo cada parte do problema, ajuda a quem vai responder focar no assunto específico. Sugestão de leitura para melhor aproveitamento do site: [Tour], [Ask] e [FAQ da comunidade](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/699).

Comment: oi, guilherme no win7 tinha o controle dos pais, que seria a base do meu projeto, agora no win10 essa ferramenta não existe, é uma pena a evolução dos programas para pior, a tua dica seria boa, se bloqueasse para todos os usuários, primeiro para fazer isso tem que ser admin depois só bloquei o admin, e os outros usuários continua livre.

Comment: @NilceliaPereira em ambas respostas você terá que rodar como administrador ou serviço, isto não é um problema com o código, mas sim com o Windows, pois é o nivel de permissão. Ambas respostas precisarão  ser executados como administrador ou serviço para poder ter acesso a todos usuários.

Comment: pessoal primeiro meus agradecimentos a todos que me ajudaram, e desculpe a demora no feedback, fim de ano, trabalho, e realmente não consegui executar as ideia oferecidas, pois eu usava "chrome.exe" e sofri até descobri que se eu tirar o ".exe" ai bloqueia, se não passa pelo forech, para bloquear o chrome seria "chrome", para start seria com o exe, um detalhe que não prestei atenção, valeu a todos, vou repetir o comentaria em todas as respostas se errei me corija, muito obrigada a todos que me ajudaram.

Answer (score 4):

Primeiro deve-se aprender o básico do c# e provavelmente do VisualStudio, não tem como pular passos, isto só fará o caminho ser mais duro. Depois de aprender sobre:

- Variáveis
- Funções
- Classes
- Orientação a objetos
- Sobre as praticas dos métodos nas classes do csharp
- Compilar um HelloWorld com Console e um com Windows Form

Então fazendo isto você pode começar a estudar as bibliotecas nativas (e não nativas).

Após ter estudado o básico, um exemplo de matar uma aplicação que é o que você deseja, para bloquear é necessário o `kill`, será necessário um loop "infinito":

```
new Thread(() =>
{
    while (true)
    {
        Thread.Sleep(100);

        Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("NOME DO PROCESSO QUE DESEJA BLOQUEAR");

        foreach (Process pr in ps)
        {
            pr.Kill();
            pr.Close();
        }
    }
}).Start();
```

> Nota: Troque o `"NOME DO PROCESSO QUE DESEJA BLOQUEAR"` pelo nome do processo que deseja bloquear.

Com o `Process.GetProcessesByName` você pode pegar o processo pelo nome, então com o `foreach` você pode listar todas instancias abertas e "mata-las", provavelmente ele deverá ficar dentro de um loop infinito em outra `Thread`.

Sendo console acho que não será necessário o Thread, a não ser que você queira colocar comandos de Input, mas acaso seja apenas para bloquear (não pude testar):

```
using System;

public class BloquearProcessos
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("NOME DO PROCESSO QUE DESEJA BLOQUEAR");

            foreach (Process pr in ps)
            {
                pr.Kill();
                pr.Close();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Acaso seja um `Form` o próprio visual studio já cria uma estrutura basica, mas se não souber aonde aplicar o código segue um exemplo:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Thread eventThread = new Thread(() =>
            {
                while (true)
                {
                    Thread.Sleep(100);

                    Process[] ps = Process.GetProcessesByName("NOME DO PROCESSO QUE DESEJA BLOQUEAR");

                    foreach (Process pr in ps)
                    {
                        pr.Kill();
                        pr.Close();
                    }
                }
            });

            eventThread.IsBackground = true;
            eventThread.Start();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: oi, trabalho com C# e visual studio a 2 anos, mas ainda me enrosco nos detalhes, mas obrigada.

Comment: @NilceliaPereira Que legal, então teste o `Process.GetProcessesByName` e me diga o resultado.

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento não mecho com C#, mas pelo que eu entendi a sua solução mata o programa depois que ele tenha sido aberto. A pergunta é sobre como impedir um executável de abrir no Windows. Acredito que a AP queira uma funcionalidade parecida com a dos *Anti-Virus* que **impedem** que um vírus seja executado quando o usuário tenta abri-lo.

Comment: @OlimonF. É exatamente isto que o Anti-Virus faz, por isto o código deve ficar em `loop` infinito, por exemplo, já usou o blockfree? Então ele funciona mais ou menos assim. A diferença é que os anti-virus fazem um scan no executavel.

Comment: obrigada a todos, nunca vi um fórum tão introrsado, perdoa a demora mas estou tentando colocar as dicas na pratica.

Comment: @NilceliaPereira desculpe mas não somos um fórum, por favor leia o veja Tour: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour - Teste e tente as respostas o tempo que for necessário, só não esqueça de dar um feedback em caso de problemas ;)

Comment: infelizmente não consegui, abro meu programa  mas não bloqueia nada, coloquei o código no inicializável, mas nada adiantou.

Comment: NilceliaPereira você colocou o código dentro de um Thread em loop infinito? Veja eu editei a resposta, verifica se funciona por favor. Nota: Troque o "NOME DO PROCESSO QUE DESEJA BLOQUEAR" pelo nome do processo que deseja bloquear.

Comment: Esta resposta possui dois pontos que não considero boas práticas. Uma, o uso indiscriminado de Process.Kill(). De acordo com a MSDN, 'o método Kill causa uma finalização anormal do processo e deve ser usado apenas quando realmente necessário' (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.kill(v=vs.110).aspx#Anchor_2). Segundo, o processamento de um loop infinito esperando por uma aplicação ser lançada. Uma abordagem melhor seria a monitoração dos eventos de inicialização de aplicativos via ManagementEventWatcher.

Comment: @lbotinelly Obrigado pelas dicas +1, raramente programo pra desktop e windows :/ - Vou estudar e no sábado edito a resposta ;)

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento sem estresse, estamos todos aqui pra aprender. =)

Comment: pessoal primeiro meus agradecimentos a todos que me ajudaram, e desculpe a demora no feedback, fim de ano, trabalho, e realmente não consegui executar as ideia oferecidas, pois eu usava "chrome.exe" e sofri até descobri que se eu tirar o ".exe" ai bloqueia, se não passa pelo forech, para bloquear o chrome seria "chrome", para start seria com o exe, um detalhe que não prestei atenção, valeu a todos, vou repetir o comentaria em todas as respostas se errei me corija, muito obrigada a todos que me ajudaram.

Comment: @NilceliaPereira realmente coisas de windows, tem que tirar o .exe :p